# Unit Testing with different behaviour on existance of a file

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd, testng

There are some cases that the software shall behave differently according to some environmental conditions, for example whether a file exists at some place or not.

In my case, I'm developing a library, and it is configured according to a configuration file in classpath, (and falls back to default behavior if the config file does not exists).

How shall I unit test this class?
I need to write tests for evaluating the class in following cases:

- the file does not exists on classpath
- the file with content A exist on classpath
- the file with content B exist on classpath

But I don't know how to configure environment to justify all of them. And execute the test one after each other.

By the way I'm using Java, and I have both JUnit and TestNG on the test classpath.

---

Edit:
One of the problems is that the config file resides in classpath, so if the *normal ClassLoader* finds and loads it, it returns the same content as long as the same class loader is used.
And I believe using a custom ClassLoader for testing is so complicated, that it needs tests to validate the tests!

Comment: Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Keep the environment (file system, env variables, network, time / date, databases) out of your unit tests. It's a pain. Just mock everything.

Comment: @Robert I want to do that, but what about the production environment? In the target deployment, I need to check the for existence of a classpath file. Isn't it required the behavior on tests too?

Comment: I wouldn't consider that a unit test anymore, but an integration test

Answer (score 1):

You can use a temporary file created by your test to mock out the path in your class.

ConfigurationTest.java:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.junit.Assume.assumeThat;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ConfigurationTest {

    private Configuration config = new Configuration();

    @Test
    public void testWithConfigFile() throws Exception {
        config.configFile = Files.createTempFile("config_",".ini");
        config.configFile.toFile().deleteOnExit();
        assertFalse(config.isInDefaultMode());
    }
    @Test
    public void testWithoutConfigFile() throws Exception {
        assumeThat(Files.exists(config.configFile), is(false));
        assertTrue(config.isInDefaultMode());
    }
}
```

Configuration.java:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Configuration {

    Path configFile = Paths.get("config.ini");

    public boolean isInDefaultMode() {
        return !Files.exists(configFile);
    }
}
```